# Recursive JSON Generation Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, recursion

This is going to be a bit long winded, but here goes:

I am writing two separate web applications: one for generating a JSON object with a bunch of data and formatting information and another for turning that JSON object into a nice formatted HTML page for viewing. The particular issue I am having currently is with nested lists.

For the viewing application, I wrote a recursive function that will parse the supplied javascript object and create the HTML for a list with an arbitrary magnitude of nested elements.

```
function createUnorderedList(object) {
    var ul = $('<ol>');

    for (var i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
        if (object[i].children === undefined) {
            ul.append($('<li>').text(object[i].value));
        } else {
            ul.append(
            $('<li>').html(
            object[i].value + "<ul>" + createUnorderedList(object[i].children) + "</ul>"));
        }
    }

    return ul.html();
}
```

The jsfiddle for that function can be seen here: [jsfiddle: Recursive HTML List Generation](https://jsfiddle.net/simonpaonessa/bedmvx43/5/)

Now, I need to create a function for the JSON creation side of things. Having tried and failed to wrap my brain around how to do this recursively, I settled upon a more linear function, seen here:

```
function createList( array ) {
    var json = { "value": [] } ;
    var k = 0 ;
    if(array[array.length-1] === "") array.pop() ;
    for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++ ){
        json.value.push( { "value": array[i] } ) ;
        for(var j=i+1; j<array.length; j++) {
            if(array[j].charAt(0) === '\t') {
                array[j] = array[j].replace( /\t/, '' ) ;
                i++;
                if(json.value[k].children === undefined)
                    $.extend( json.value[k], { children : [] } ) ;
                json.value[k].children.push( { "value": array[j] } ) ;
            } else { k++; j=array.length; }
        }
    }
    return json ;
}
```

[jsfiddle: JSON List Generation](https://jsfiddle.net/simonpaonessa/fo1ffL76/11/).

This function can only handle a nested list of one order of magnitude, which should suffice for now but is not ideal. How can I make this function capable of generating a json object with an arbitrary magnitude of nested elements?

Thank you.

Comment: I would make an array of tuples. Objects are not ordered. This may not give you the result you want.

Comment: Also, you can simplify your logic by using `Array.prototype.reduce()`. See [`makeOrderedList3() in my example`](https://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/hy63b46a/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**: I misunderstood your question at first.

This is how you can parse a `ul` hierarchy into an object (view the JS console to see what is parsed out):

```js
function itemsToHierarchy(node) {
    return $(node).find('> ul > li').toArray().map(function (item) {
        return {
            value: item.childNodes[0].textContent,
            children: itemsToHierarchy(item)
        };
    });
}

console.log(itemsToHierarchy($('#list')));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- leaving the HTML scrunched up to save space -->
<div id="list"><ul><li>Item 1<ul><li>Item 1.1</li></ul></li><li>Item 2</li><li>Item 3<ul><li>Item 3.1</li><li>Item 3.2<ul><li>Item 3.2.1<ul><li>Item 3.2.1.1</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li><li>Item 4<ul><li>Item 4.1</li><li>Item 4.2</li></ul></li><li>Item 5<ul><li>Item 5.1</li></ul></li></ul></div>
```

At first I thought you were asking for help with your `createList()` function. Here is a recursive version that works for any nesting depth:

```
function getItems( array, depth ) {
    depth = depth || 0;
    var items = [],
        item = array.shift();

    while (item && countTabs(item) === depth) {
        items.push({
            value: item.replace(/^\t*/, ''),
            children: getItems(array, depth + 1)
        });
        item = array.shift();
    }

    if (item) { // not at this depth
        array.unshift(item);
    }

    return items;    
}

function countTabs(value) {
    return value.match(/^\t*/)[0].length;
}
```

The value returned from that can be used to build the HTML as follows:

```
function createUnorderedList(items) {
    return $('<ul>').append($.map(items, function (item) {
        var li = $('<li>').text(item.value);

        if (item.children.length) {
            li.append(createUnorderedList(item.children));
        }

        return li;
    }));        
}
```

Full solution: https://jsfiddle.net/1930t20f/

Comment: This solution looks like it should work (though I didn't include the "children" element if there are no children, but now I'm just being picky). Thank you for your help! Cheers :-)

Comment: @SimonPaonessa Yes, I know you were leaving children undefined when there were none and the above approach could be fairly easily modified to do so, but I think that having empty arrays of children is more consistent and allows for cleaner algorithms without any null checks.

Comment: Hahah. Maybe you're right. Like I said, not a big deal.

Comment: You can replace `console.log(itemsToHierarchy($('#list')));` with `$(document).append('<code>'+itemsToHierarchy($('#list'))+'</code>');` (or similar)

Answer (score 0):

After some hard thinking I found a solution.

First I changed your code to create a `<li>` for every value. The children are the a `<ul>` after the `<li>`.

```
function createUnorderedList(object) {
    var ul = $('<ul>');
    for (var i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
        ul.append($('<li>').text(object[i].value));
        if (object[i].children) {
            ul.append($('<ul>').html(createUnorderedList(object[i].children)));
        }
    }
    return ul.html();
}
```

Then I created a function that searches recursively all elements. The `<ul>` is the child of the `<li>` before it.

```
var createJSONRecursive = function(elem, arr) {
    var childNodes = elem.childNodes;
    var nodeTmp;
    for (var i = 0; i<childNodes.length; i++) {
        var node = {};
        var tagName = childNodes[i].tagName;
        if (tagName == 'LI') {
            node.value = childNodes[i].innerHTML;
            if (i < childNodes.length - 1 && childNodes[i+1].tagName == 'UL') {
                nodeTmp = node;
            }
            else {
                arr.push(node);
            }
        }
        else if (tagName == 'UL') {
            nodeTmp.children = [];
            createJSONRecursive(childNodes[i], nodeTmp.children);        
            arr.push(nodeTmp);
        }        
    }    
}

var createJSON = function(elem) {
    var json = {value:[]}
    createJSONRecursive(elem, json.value);
    return json;    
}

var json = createJSON(document.getElementById('div'));
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8qc2mcyz/2/

Comment: Probably not a big deal, but this solution relies on having `<ul>`s directly inside other `<ul>`s, which is not technically valid HTML.

Comment: This isn't quite what I was trying to do, but it is certainly helpful. I was looking to generate the JSON object from user input in a textarea, where tabs would indicate hierarchy. The string that I am using in the second jsfiddle that I linked to would be (essentially) the input I'd be working with. You got me on the right track though, so thank you. Cheers. :-)